# Send data from c# to a php page and display on php

Tags: c#, php

I'm using altervista which dosn't allow a connection directly with the database but only from php scripts stored on the server. Searching on the web I foud the solution, passing the data from c# to the php's URL either with Get or Post method. Then I wrote this little code in c#

```
    private void SubmitData()
    {
        try
        {
            string url = "";
            string str = "test";
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            string Data = "message=" + str;
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
            Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();


    }
    catch (WebException)
    {

        MessageBox.Show("Please Check Your Internet Connection");
    }
}
```

Php code

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_POST['message']))
    {
        $msg = $_POST['message'];

        echo $msg;

    }
    else
    {
        echo "couldn't display data";
    }

   ?>
```

It doen't ever seem that it sends some data to it.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: is there something in 'responseText'?

Comment: It prints out "test".

Comment: so your code works... Whats your Problem?

Comment: The point is, why can't I display it on the php page when I realod it?

Comment: Do I understand this in the right manner? You want the same value that you post by C# also appear when reloading the page in the web browser?

Comment: Yes sir, that's right

Comment: Ok, then the answer is not that easy. You have to understand that PHP generates a new response for every request to the server. If you want to store a value in PHP across multiple queries, you must save that value to a database or to a file. For each request, you can then load the value if it exists and show it

Comment: I mean for saving the data I get that, but for displaying it only the first time, why doesn't php code work for that?

Comment: For each request, the PHP script is re-executed, so PHP forgets every variable every time. PHP was not designed to store a variable for a long time for all requests. Exactly for this situation one can use databases or files

Comment: I'm trying to store that variable from php to my database, it has nothing inside, I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, it will sound really stupid but I didn't actualy execute the program, that was bad from me, anyway, could you please explain me why I'm getting another string from the variable responseText, which is actually an echo message that I display on my web page, thank you so much.